# Changing the Data from server in knock out js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a statemodel like this:

```
 var stateModel = {
     StateId: ko.observable(0),
     StateName: ko.observable('').extend({ required: true }).extend({ pattern: { message: 'Enter only Text', params: '^[a-zA-Z ]*$'} }),
     ShortName: ko.observable('')
                     .extend({ required: true })
                     .extend({ pattern: 
                                 { message: 'Enter only Text', params: '^[a-zA-Z ]*$'}
                             }),
     IsActive: ko.observable(true),
     CountryId: ko.observable().extend({ required: true })    
}
```

And i am posting it by converting into json string by following :

```
  var args=JSON.stringify({argBO: jQuery.parseJSON(ko.toJSON(self.StateModel))});
```

after this i want to push this to my observable array StateList() ,so i am converting it into objects and pushing it like:

```
   var model = jQuery.parseJSON(ko.toJSON(self.StateModel));
   self.StatesList.push(model);
```

My args will look like this:

```
   {"argBO":
      { "StateId":0, 
        "StateName":"jjhj",
        "ShortName":"jjj",
        "IsActive":true,
        "CountryId":8,
        "errors":[],
        "CountryName":"Antigua and Barbud"
      }
    }
```

If i could remove the argBO From above i can directly push the 'args' rather than self.StateModel, again  by converting args into objects.

```
self.StatesList.Push(args);
```

I tried like this :

```
jQuery.parseJSON(args(jQuery.parseJSON(argBO)))
jQuery.parseJSON(args(jQuery.parseJSON[argBO]))
jQuery.parseJSON(args[argBO]))
```

But none of them working please anybody tell me!!

Comment: Why? I mean, why do you `parseJSON` a `toJSON`?

Comment: i only want to push 'argBO' objects into my observable arrays not 'args' every time

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var JSONargs = jQuery.parseJSON(ko.toJSON(self.StateModel));
```

OR if you use the knockout.mapping.js plugin:

```
var JSONargs = ko.mapping.toJS(self.StateModel);
```

When you want to post it, you can do:

```
$.ajax({data: JSON.stringify({ argBO: JSONargs });
```

And then your push could be like

```
self.StatesList.Push(JSONargs);
```

Comment: I tried this console.log(ko.utils.parseJson(args).argBO.StateName) , it is printing me correct value of my StateName , where as if i try to change the StateName like  ko.utils.parseJson(args).argBO.StateName = 'asdf'; it is not changing..why